# WPF UI rendering quality difference between designer and runtime

Tags: wpf

I have rendering issues when running my app, some elements appear blurry and faded, the same elements looks just fine when displayed in the designer. I have noticed that this happens especially in certain cases, when using drop shadow effect for example or border rounded edges sometimes.
Using "SnapsToDevicePixels = True" and "UseLayoutRounding = True" is helpless, I used them in parent element and every other related element with no hope.

I found my app executable displayed very well on some other machines.

Is there Windows-wide settings for WPF that I should adjust or something like that?
Thank you.

I'm using VS 2017 Community on a Windows 10 older machine.

Comment: In your code, make it possible to switch to software rendering. Then on those machines that trigger blurry, do switch to software rendering and see if things go better. Sounds like video card driver bugs.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to force software rendering (using RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly during app startup event) but found the same issue. And yes me too think about video card issues, may be, because when I upgraded to Windows 10 I found that my video card is not fully supported by it. But that makes me expect a different result when forcing software rendering !